# Apache2 "Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, web-hosting

Hi everyone I have a problem on Apache2 (on ubuntu). My server does not starts up and when I enter `systemctl status apache2.service` I see this;

```
        ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-01-12 13:11:24 +03; 22min ago
  Process: 7336 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro apachectl[7336]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro apachectl[7336]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro apachectl[7336]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro apachectl[7336]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro apachectl[7336]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro apachectl[7336]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro apachectl[7336]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 12 13:11:24 lvlzyro systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely either Apache or another webserver (e.g. nginx) is already running. To check for that, grep the process list for `apache`, `httpd` and `nginx` or use `netstat -anp | grep ':80\s'` to find out.

After you have understood which process uses port 80, you can decide if you want to terminate it or if you have an unsupported configuration and can't use Apache on port 80

Comment: To add to this, if OP wants to run multiple webservers they can change the port from 80 to another one, and access it using <hostname>:<port> (For example, say you want to access the local webserver on port 85, you would navigate to http://localhost:85 ). As always, port forward these if you wish to access it outside of your network.

Answer (score -1):

You need to **disable firewall** 
and then **restart PC**

code: `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: The firewall is not related to the error in the log.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for letting me know. But once I got this error & I solved it by the above solution which I mentioned.

Comment: @ParthDevloper Not sure if a blocked port will result in the same error with Apache as a port already in used (doubt it) but disabling the firewall should not be done. Firewalls have a purpose. You can always `allow` a specific port/port range/type of traffic on a port and also check the `status` of the firewall to list the rules you have in place.